# IndexOutOfBoundsException with Timer in Java

Tags: java, methods, timer, arraylist, fibonacci

I have a problem which hopefully requires a simple obvious solution I can't seem figure out. Ok, so I'm playing around with Fibonacci Sequence: I want to prompt the user to enter an Integer. Then it will run the sequence adding each element to an Arraylist. Then, I want to display each element from the array list to the console using a timer - with each element from the sequence displayed each second - I do this in a short method.

The output is fine. Just when I run the program I get the IndexOutOfBoundsException. I understand why the problem occurs. My count exceeds the size of the array list. I thought about just messing around with >,=,etc - but didn't solve the problem. I thought about resolving the error with a while loop - that didn't work. My question is: how do I count up without exceeding the index limit of my array list?

Here is my code:

```
public class Sequence {

static int seconds = 0;
static Timer timer;
static ArrayList<Integer> fibList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean noError = true; 
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    //will store sum of evens
    int tmp = 0;

    //timer variables
    int delay = 1000;
    int period = 1000;
    timer = new Timer();

    //enter user input, try catch to eliminate invalid input
    do{
        try{
            System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
            int input = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

            //add to arraylist from user input
            for (int i=0; i<=input; i++){
                   fibList.add(fib(i));

                   //sum even numbers
            if(fib(i)%2 == 0){
                tmp += fib(i);
            }

            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Not a valid Number!");

        }

        noError = false;
    }while(noError);

     System.out.println(fibList);
     System.out.println("Sum of Even Numbers is: "+tmp);


     timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            public void run() {      

                System.out.print(fibList.get(setInterval())+ ",");
            }
        }, delay, period);

}

    //This is where I count up through my ArrayList and probably cause the Error
//counts up for every element through the array
public static final int setInterval() {

    if (seconds >= fibList.size())
        timer.cancel();
    return seconds++;


}

//does fibonacci sequence
public static int fib(int n) {
    if (n < 2) {
         return n;
      }
      else {
   return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2);
      }
```

}

}

Answer (score 1):

`iluxa`'s approach is better by the way. The logic is clean and avoids confusion.

But, if you just want to fix your test condition change your `if` to

```
if (seconds == fibList.size() - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

you are returning a `seconds++` from `setInterval()` and using that to get the array list element, even after you already canceled the timer cause you know you've gone too far. Instead, you should do smth like

```
public void run() {      
  int nextIndex = setInterval();
  if (nextIndex < fibList.size()) {
    System.out.print(fibList.get(nextIndex)+ ",");
  }
}
```

That way, you won't try to print out an index that's too large; and the thread will get cancelled before next iteration